# h1 centered and with a bakground color adjusted to the text size

Tags: css

Im trying to have an `<h1>` centered and with a background color adjusted to the text size. As you can see, now it is not centered. This is my try:

```
<h1>this text must be centered</h1>

h1 {
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UtL4N/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do it as follows. You should use `display:table;` for `h1`.

```
<h1>this text must be centered</h1>

h1 {
    background-color: red;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UtL4N/2/)